# Printing the contents of a <rich:modalPanel />?

Tags: java, jsf, seam, richfaces

Attempting to print the contents of a `<rich:modalPanel />` in my application results in a complete mess on the printed page.

The complete HTML *underlying* the `<rich:modalPanel />` appears on the printed page, but completely faded out (as it sort of appears on screen). And *somewhere* on that page, is the `<rich:modalPanel />` content itself - what the user *actually wanted* to print.

The expected behavior is to *just* print the `<rich:modalPanel />` content, occupying the entire printed page. How would I configure this behavior, or what alternative media (`media="print"`) styles do I need to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and based on the HTML Code this will not be possible out of the box. I solved the problem by using http://plugins.jquery.com/project/printElement which is jQuery based function that allows to print single HTML Code Elements.

Maybe this will help you too.